# Relationship between Van der Waals forces and the boiling point

Tags: homework, molecules

Choose the right answers in the following statement:

The boiling point of a liquid substance is higher as the Van der Waals forces (in/between) the molecules of the substance are (lower/higher).

I don't understand why the Van der Waals forces are lower when the boiling point is lower. Second, do you say: the forces *in* the molecules of a substance or the forces *between* the molecules of a substance?

Answer (score 1):

We talk about the forces between molecules.  The Van der Waals force represents the summation of all attractive and repulsive forces between molecules, other than those due to electrostatic charges or actual bonds.  This summation most often turns out to be a weak attractive force.  Typically the magnitude of the Van der Waals force is small compared to electrostatic or bonding forces and (again typically) only apply at relatively short range.  So they usually serve to weakly hold molecules together.  The stronger the Van der Waals force, the more strongly molecules will be held together and the more energy will be needed to be put into the system to break them apart from each other.  In the case of boiling a liquid, you are really talking about breaking molecules apart from one another.  So in the case of boiling, the weaker the Van der Waals attraction between molecules, less energy will needed to break them apart from each other and allow them to boil.

Here is a [link to a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) on Van der Waals forces if you'd like to read more about them.

Comment: The van der Waals force is the sum of the attractive or repulsive forces between molecules (or between parts of the same molecule) other than those due to covalent bonds, the hydrogen bonds, or the electrostatic interaction of ions with one another or with neutral molecules or charged molecules.